# How accurate is the Gmail account activity listing?

Tags: gmail

I have a Gmail account that I have been checking every day. When I click on the Details link (near the bottom of the page), and check the recent activity, sometimes the days on which I know I checked my email are not listed.

Is this something to be concerned about? Or is it some glitch in Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing to be concerned about.  This page is meant to show you unusual sessions compared to a usage pattern over time.  Look for odd items, like an IP address from another country for or a browser you never use.

Through trial and error, I have found that the details page list is dependent on how you use your account.

If you use one browser on one computer then the details page seems to list last authentication session more than "last checked email".  Meaning days you checked email might not be listed, especially if you leave your browser open for days.